# PHPExcel insert array formula

Tags: php, phpexcel, array-formulas

I want to insert this array formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(T9:T977=1,MATCH(U9:U977,U9:U977,0)),ROW(U9:U977)-ROW(U9)+1),1))}
```

but when I'm using:

```
$sheet->getCell("C1")->setValue("{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(T9:T977=1,MATCH(U9:U977,U9:U977,0)),ROW(U9:U977)-ROW(U9)+1),1))}");
```

It doesn't work, I've checked the documentation, but still haven't found anything.

Comment: Does the formula work in excel without errors?

Comment: Array formulas are not supported by PHPExcel

Comment: Made a solution down below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any answer so I went through PHPExcel and made myself a solution:

`in /PHPExcel/Cell.php` at row 251 in the `switch($pDataType)` add this:

```
case PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA_ARRAY:
$this->_value = (string)$pValue;
break;
```

`in /PHPExcel/Cell/DataType.php` add this constant:

```
const TYPE_FORMULA_ARRAY = 't';
```

At last in `/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Worksheet.php`I've added this in the switch beginning at row 1095:

```
case 't':           // Array Formulae
    $objWriter->startElement('f');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('t', 'array');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('ref', $pCellAddress);
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('aca', '1');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('ca', '1');
    $objWriter->text($cellValue);
    $objWriter->endElement();               
    if ($this->getParentWriter()->getOffice2003Compatibility() === false) {
        if ($this->getParentWriter()->getPreCalculateFormulas()) {
            $calculatedValue = $pCell->getCalculatedValue();
            if (!is_array($calculatedValue) && substr($calculatedValue, 0, 1) != '#') {
                $objWriter->writeElement('v', PHPExcel_Shared_String::FormatNumber($calculatedValue));
            } else {
                $objWriter->writeElement('v', '0');
            }
        } else {
            $objWriter->writeElement('v', '0');
    }
}
break;
```

Then I used the function like this:

```
$sheet->getCell("C1")->setValueExplicit("=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(T9:T977=1,MATCH(U9:U977,U9:U977,0)),ROW(U9:U977)-ROW(U9)+1),1))", PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA_ARRAY);
```

And it works all good when I'm creating a excel file!

Comment: You did such a good job here, but why not complete it? At the moment you can only set array function for 1 cell?

Answer (score 5):

Since this question/answer still comes up when searching for PHPExcel's successor, PHPSpreadsheet, I'd like to add that the latter has support for array formulas build in. Just assign the formula as usual and set the type-attribute to array:

```
$attrs = $sheet->getCell("C1")->getFormulaAttributes();
$attrs['t'] = 'array';
$sheet->getCell("C1")->setFormulaAttributes($attrs);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have spent the last day and half looking for this.  I don't see any mention in the PhpSpreadsheet documents.  Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fix for inserting array formula using PhpSpreadsheet.
I have made few changes in function 'writeCellFormula'
(PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet.php)

**Usage:**

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$attrs = $sheet->getCell("C1")->getFormulaAttributes();
$attrs['t'] = 'array';
$sheet->getCell("C1")->setFormulaAttributes($attrs);
$sheet->setCellValue("C1",'=SUM(A1:A3*B1:B3)');
```

**Expected output:** {=SUM(Q1:Q3*R1:R3) }

```
private function writeCellFormula(XMLWriter $objWriter, string $cellValue, Cell $pCell): void
{
    $attributes = $pCell->getFormulaAttributes();
    if ($attributes['t']=='array')
    {
        $pCellAddress = $pCell->getCoordinate();
        $objWriter->startElement('f');
        $objWriter->writeAttribute('t', 'array');
        $objWriter->writeAttribute('ref', $pCellAddress);
        //$objWriter->writeAttribute('aca', '1');
        //$objWriter->writeAttribute('ca', '1');
        $objWriter->text(substr($cellValue, 1));
        $objWriter->endElement();
        return;
    }
    
    $calculatedValue = $this->getParentWriter()->getPreCalculateFormulas() ? $pCell->getCalculatedValue() : $cellValue;
    if (is_string($calculatedValue)) {
        if (\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Functions::isError($calculatedValue)) {
            $this->writeCellError($objWriter, 'e', $cellValue, $calculatedValue);

            return;
        }
        $objWriter->writeAttribute('t', 'str');
    } 
    elseif (is_bool($calculatedValue) ) {
        $objWriter->writeAttribute('t', 'b');
        $calculatedValue = (int) $calculatedValue;
    }

    $objWriter->writeElement('f', Xlfn::addXlfnStripEquals($cellValue));
    self::writeElementIf(
        $objWriter,
        $this->getParentWriter()->getOffice2003Compatibility() === false,
        'v',
        ($this->getParentWriter()->getPreCalculateFormulas() && !is_array($calculatedValue) && substr($calculatedValue, 0, 1) !== '#')
            ? StringHelper::formatNumber($calculatedValue) : '0'
    );
}
```

Comment: Editing the files of a library is ***never*** an acceptable solution. Override the class if you have to, but xrm's answer from last year suggests this functionality is now built-in to the library.