# Formula having the @ symbol added

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have been creating several formulas and adding them to a PhpSpreadsheet without any issues. But when I created the following formula, added to the PhpSpreadsheet and opened the xlsx file 6 of the 8 rows had '#VALUE!'

The formula is calculating the STDEV for a range of cells that are greater than or equal to a minimum value and less than or equal to a maximum value.

The formula was created like this:

```
$cf_mP_Stdev =
   "=STDEV(IF(('" . $samplesWellsSheetName . "'!" . $mpCol . ($writeSampleWellsRow - 319) . ":" . $mpCol . $writeSampleWellsRow . ">=J" . $writeControlPlatesRow . ")*('" .
   $samplesWellsSheetName . "'!" . $mpCol . ($writeSampleWellsRow - 319) . ":" . $mpCol . $writeSampleWellsRow . "<=L" . $writeControlPlatesRow . "),'" .
   $samplesWellsSheetName . "'!" . $mpCol . ($writeSampleWellsRow - 319) . ":" . $mpCol . $writeSampleWellsRow . "))";
```

In Excel I was expecting:

```
=STDEV(IF(('Samples-Wells'!H3:H322>=J4)*('Samples-Wells'!H3:H322<=L4),'Samples-Wells'!H3:H322))
```

but when I opened my xlsx file it had '@' symbols in front of two of the three ranges:

```
=STDEV(IF((@'Samples-Wells'!H3:H322>=J4)*(@'Samples-Wells'!H3:H322<=L4),'Samples-Wells'!H3:H322))
```

For this formula and the next formula the calculated value was correct.  But for the next 6 formula's I received the '#VALUE!'.  Here is the third formula. No difference except that it is against the next set of cells.  Column H in the Samples-Wells worksheet has data from row 3 to 1282.

```
=STDEV(IF((@'Samples-Wells'!H323:H642 >= J6)*(@'Samples-Wells'!H323:H642 <= L6),'Samples-Wells'!H323:H642))
```

[image]

So my questions are:

- Why are the @ symbols added to the formula?  Does this come from PhpSpreadsheet or Excel?

  **Side Note:** If I manually remove the @ symbols from the formula in Excel and press enter the calculation is correct.
- Any thoughts on why the first two formulas for "Stdev mP" worked, but the last six failed?

---

Using PhpSpreadsheet 1.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to code for Array Formulas via this StackOverflow link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59930320/5359251

```
$attrs = $sheet->getCell("C1")->getFormulaAttributes();
$attrs['t'] = 'array';
$sheet->getCell("C1")->setFormulaAttributes($attrs);
```

I couldn't find anything in the PhpSpreadsheet documents.

Answer (score 0):

@ is use for number/text formatting as string maybe the problem comes from this part. I would debug into the formular while setting the value and if in the formula is an @ remove

```
var_dump($formula);
str_replace("@", "", $formula);  
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', $formula);
```

Comment: No success.  After building the string $cf_mP_Stdev I assigned it to the cell.  I then performed a getCell('P4')->getValue(); The formula was defined correctly without any '@' symbols "=STDEV(IF(('Samples-Wells'!H3:H322>=J4)*('Samples-Wells'!H3:H322<=L4),'Samples-Wells'!H3:H322))".  I have several other formulas that include references to other worksheets and they do not have the '@' being embedded "=SUMIFS('Samples-Wells'!H3:H322, 'Samples-Wells'!H3:H322, ">" & J4, 'Samples-Wells'!H3:H322, "<" & L4)/N4".

Comment: I also have other STDEV formulas that do not have the '@' symbol embedded "=STDEV('Controls-Wells'!I3:I18)".  Any thought if it has something to do with this specific STDEV formula that is basically doing an 'AND' with the '*'?

Comment: An additional note:  I am opening this file on Microsoft Excel for Mac (V16.35).  If I open on Excels for Windows there are no @ symbols and if I press Ctrl-Shirt-Enter in each cell it is calculated.  Didn't think about Array Formulas.  Need to figure what is occurring in Excel for Mac

Comment: @ChrisWolcott you mean if you press Ctrl-Shift-Enter in the cell in Excel for _Windows_, right? I.e. in Excel for Mac the formula is just useless. Or did I misunderstand? Did you find anything else about that @ sign?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34), they say

> The implicit intersection operator was introduced as part of
> substantial upgrade to Excel's formula language to support dynamic
> arrays. Dynamic arrays bring significant new calculation ability and
> functionality to Excel.

and

> Generally speaking, functions that return multi-cell ranges or arrays
> will be prefixed with @ if they were authored in an older version of
> Excel.

So if you open the exported file with recent Excel versions, they will automatically add the @ symbol if the formula is not an array one. And I've tried the solution OP suggested, but it seems like it is not possible to write array formulas using PHPSpreadsheet.

I'm still looking for other solutions.